# Model -> SoftDelete

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a softdelete however I have an ask. In the model we must to do as that:

```
class Devis extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

My problem is I must to format also the date therefore how to do ? 
Is it correct to do as that ?

```
class Devis extends Model
    {
        protected $dates = ['date, deleted_at'];
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes. You can add in the `$dates` array as many attributes as you want. All of them will be casted as an instance of `Carbon ` when querying.

Comment: You're close, but not quite there. Each column needs to be quoted separately. `protected $dates = ['date', 'deleted_at'];`

Comment: You need to use the SoftDeletes trait. `use SoftDeletes;` Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: @HCK; @aynber; @adam; thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$dates` attribute on a model is an *array* of attribute names that Laravel will cast to a (Carbon) Date class.

Standard PHP array syntax applies:

```
protected $dates = ['date', 'deleted_at'];
```

(Don't forget to `use SoftDeletes` in the model if you haven't)